# Even though I have install right version of pytorch and torchvision (1.11 & 0.12), I am getting this massage while running the program in raspberrypi

Tags: python, pytorch, raspberry-pi, torchvision

Pytorch 1.11
Torchvision 0.12
python 3.9

Note: I have noticed my PyTorch and Torchvision paths are different. (no virtual environment)

if the path is the reason, then how to change it

The Error::

RuntimeError: Couldn't load custom C++ ops. This can happen if your PyTorch and torchvision versions are incompatible, or if you had errors while compiling torchvision from source. For further information on the compatible versions, check https://github.com/pytorch/vision#installation for the compatibility matrix. Please check your PyTorch version with torch__version__ and your torchvision version with torchvision__version__ and verify if they are compatible, and if not please reinstall torchvision so that it matches your PyTorch install.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.